# Is it possible to know the cpu utilization from a script

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is there any command or possible way to know the cpu utilization in windows operating system for use on the command line or in a batch script?

Comment: Related: [Get CPU Usage from Windows Command Prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097067/get-cpu-usage-from-windows-command-prompt)

Answer (score 33):

To determine the usage in general, you can use mcstellar and warren's answer.  You also have the option of:

List all processes:

`typeperf "\Process(*)\% Processor Time" -sc 1`

List all processes, take 5 samples at 10 second intervals:

`typeperf "\Process(*)\% Processor Time" -si 10 -sc 5`

If you want a specific process, Rtvscan for example:

`typeperf "\Process(Rtvscan)\% Processor Time" -si 10 -sc 5`

I found it extremely useful to just monitor all process activity over a period of time.  I could then dump it to a csv file and filter in a spreadsheet to remotely diagnose issues.

The following gives me 5 minutes (at 10 second intervals) of all processes.  The data includes not just % Processor Time, but IO, memory, paging, etc.

`typeperf -qx "\Process" > config.txt`
`typeperf -cf config.txt -o perf.csv -f CSV -y -si 10 -sc 60`

Comment: What happen if a new process is launched during your 5 minutes period? Will its activity be logged?

Comment: On my system the command typeperf -qx "\Process" > config.txt does not work well because it adds to config.txt also the string "Exiting please wait... The command completed successfully." in the middle of the counters. It works well if I replace the redirection with the -o typeperf option.

Comment: with "typeperf -q" you can get all list of QUERY parameters.

Answer (score 15):

To monitor at 1 second intervals use:

```
typeperf "\processor(_total)\% processor time"
```

For only the current usage, use:

```
typeperf -sc 1 "\processor(_total)\% processor time"
```

Answer (score 5):

From the command line?  Have a look at PsList in the [PsTools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx) suite.

Comment: `pslist` only shows CPU time and elapsed time, which requires extra calculation to get a utilization number, and is not a "real time" number but process lifetime number.  For a quick "who's using my CPU" this isn't so useful, though it could be good for other uses.

Answer (score 5):

here's a little vbscript that shows cpu utilization for each process

```
strComputer ="."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process",,48)
For Each obj in colProcess
If obj.Name <> "Idle"  And obj.Name <> "_Total" Then 
        WScript.echo obj.Name & "," & obj.PercentProcessorTime
End If
Next
```

save as showcpu.vbs and run it on the command line as

```
c:\test> cscript //nologo showcpu.vbs
```