# CPU percentage utilisation per process in windows 7

Tags: visual-c++

I am using WMI interface to get various counter values like memory/ disk/IO utilisations. I also got total percentage CPU utilisation using WIN32_Process class.

But I need percentage CPU utilisation per process. Please help me out with C/C++/VC++/JAVA code to do this.

I am using VS2010 as IDE.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415085/is-it-possible-to-know-the-cpu-utilization-from-command-line

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through the [performance counters API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373083%28VS.85%29.aspx). It's not easy. Here are some articles which may help you:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373228(VS.85).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373169(VS.85).aspx