# Get CPU Usage from Windows Command Prompt

Tags: windows, command-prompt

How would I get total CPU Usage from Windows Command Prompt?:

Expected Output:

```
27%
```

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415085/is-it-possible-to-know-the-cpu-utilization-from-command-line

Comment: @Aziz - Related, but does not answer my question

Comment: @mdm typeperf "\processor(_total)\% processor time" - But it does not work on win 7

Comment: @Mike: i know ... that's why I said "related", not "duplicate" :P

Comment: I was after the CPU utilization value as shown in the task manager but none of the answers provided here worked for me.  I used the command here instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54428361/2216471

Answer (score 106, accepted):

```
C:\> wmic cpu get loadpercentage
LoadPercentage
0
```

Or

```
C:\> @for /f "skip=1" %p in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage') do @echo %p%
4%
```

Comment: Kudos to you! I have a question for this. Do you have code for this getting the CPU Usage of a remote computer or a server?

Comment: In a doman environment with appropriate rights; `wmic /node:machinename cpu get loadpercentage` for other scenarios you will have to google *wmic remote machine*

Comment: @AlexK. adding /every:1 repeats this in a loop.

Comment: you can just use `wmic cpu get loadpercentage /value` to get the value directly instead of skipping a line

Comment: Please note: if you get an error that wmic is not recognized, the WMIC.exe resides normally in the C:\windows\system32\wbem directory, so use C:\windows\system32\wbem\wmic.exe if need be

Comment: `/value` didn't work for me, so with grep installed I used `@for /f %p in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage ^| grep -P \d+') do @echo %p%` instead

Comment: when I run: ```@for /f "skip=1" %p in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage') do @echo %p%``` I get: "4% %". what can I do to just get "4"?

Answer (score 17):

The following works correctly on Windows 7 Ultimate from an elevated command prompt:

```
C:\Windows\system32>typeperf "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time"

"(PDH-CSV 4.0)","\\vm\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time"
"02/01/2012 14:10:59.361","0.648721"
"02/01/2012 14:11:00.362","2.986384"
"02/01/2012 14:11:01.364","0.000000"
"02/01/2012 14:11:02.366","0.000000"
"02/01/2012 14:11:03.367","1.038332"

The command completed successfully.

C:\Windows\system32>
```

Or for a snapshot:

```
C:\Windows\system32>wmic cpu get loadpercentage
LoadPercentage
8
```

Answer (score 8):

```
typeperf "\processor(_total)\% processor time"
```

does work on Win7, you just need to extract the percent value yourself from the last quoted string.

Answer (score 3):

`typeperf` gives me issues when it randomly doesn't work on some computers (`Error: No valid counters.`) or if the account has insufficient rights. Otherwise, here is a way to extract just the value from its output. It still needs rounding though:

```
@for /f "delims=, tokens=2" %p in ('typeperf "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -sc 3 ^| find ":"') do @echo %~p%
```

Powershell has two cmdlets to get the percent utilization for all CPUs: `Get-Counter` (preferred) or `Get-WmiObject`:

```
Powershell "Get-Counter '\Processor(*)\% Processor Time' | Select -Expand Countersamples | Select InstanceName, CookedValue"
```

Or,

```
Powershell "Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor | Select Name, PercentProcessorTime"
```

To get the overall CPU load with formatted output exactly like the question:

```
Powershell "[string][int](Get-Counter '\Processor(*)\% Processor Time').Countersamples[0].CookedValue + '%'"
```

Or,

```
 Powershell "gwmi Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor | Select -First 1 | %{'{0}%' -f $_.PercentProcessorTime}"
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that stumbles upon this page, none of the solutions here worked for me. I found this is the way to do it (in a batch file):

```
@for /f "skip=1" %%p in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage /VALUE') do (
   for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%J in ("%%p") do echo %%J
)
```