# (Batch) "wmic cpu" issue with multi-core system

Tags: cpu, multicore, wmic

I run the "wmic cpu get loadpercentage /every:1" command on a virtual machine with 2 logical CPU cores and I get the LoadPercentage of the 1st core only, as you can see on the image attached:
[Multicore Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UG7Jv.png)

How can I get the "real" CPU utilization (i.e. the average use of the 2 cores)?

Otherwise, how can I also read the 2nd CPU usage separately?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably funny that I give an answer to MY question, but since I searched and tested a lot, I want to share one more option:

I used the "typeperf" and I found the result really close to the task manager CPU utilization.

The command for the console is:

```
typeperf "\Processor Information(_Total)\% Processor Utility"
```

or the one below for a batch file:

```
typeperf "\Processor Information(_Total)\%% Processor Utility"
```

The bad points are:

1) The output format is not very handy (e.g. "01/29/2019 21:24:26.000","8.650791" )

2) If the CPU utilization is 100%, the output is >100 (Basically ~120)

3) If the CPU utilization is 1-2%, the output is ~0.5 (Basically <1.5)

Answer (score 1):

[`Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa394271(v=vs.94)):

> The Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor formatted data class
>   performance counter class provides precalculated data from performance
>   counters that monitor aspects of processor activity. The processor is
>   the part of the computer that performs arithmetic and logical
>   computations, initiates operations on peripherals, and runs the
>   threads of processes. A computer can have multiple processors. The
>   processor object represents each processor as an instance of the
>   object.
>
> This class is shown as the Processor object in System Monitor and
>   returns the same data found in System Monitor. This class derives its
>   raw data from the corresponding raw class
>   [Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Processor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa394317(v=vs.94)). The original data source is
>   the PerfOS performance library. Data is dynamically provided for this
>   class from the performance library object by the WmiPerfInst provider.

In Windows `cmd`:

```
wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor where "NOT name = '_Total'" get name, PercentProcessorTime /every:1
```

Comment: Both my questions were solved using the Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor with the "NOT name = ..." and the "name = " syntax accordingly.

I see that the measured CPU is typically about 10% less comparing to the Task Manager's one.
However, the CPU usage is really tricky, since even task manager and performance monitor sometimes display slightly different magnitudes.