# Batch Script for fetching top 20 CPU processes

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

Is it possible to find the Top 20 processes in Ascending Order in Windows 2008 Server Operating System ?

I got one of the solutions from the below link.....

[Is it possible to know the cpu utilization from a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415085/is-it-possible-to-know-the-cpu-utilization-from-command-line)

But i would need a .bat (batch) script for the fetching the Top 20 processes in Ascending Order.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell would be better to do this:

```
ps | sort -desc cpu | select -first 20 | sort ProcessName
```

use with Batch:

```
powershell "ps | sort -desc cpu | select -first 20 | sort ProcessName"
```

Comment: & if i need to do the same by wmic then ? Any Help ?

Comment: you can use it from batch with: `powershell "ps | sort -desc cpu | select -first 20 | sort ProcessName"`